# Magento: relationship between template files and the layout XML file

Tags: layout, magento

I see that the callouts template (files in frontend\my_package\default\template\callouts) doesn't have a corresponding layout XML file (frontend\my_package\default\layout). So, I thought if I have a blank layout XML file at frontend\my_package\default\layout\callouts.xml, this will disable the callout block on the Magento front page. However, it doesn't work.

The checkout template does have a checkout.xml layout file, so making this a blank file removes the checkout out block from the page I'm looking at. For the checkout block case, does the checkout.xml override what is called from the active catalog.xml? I don't remove the corresponding lines from catalog.xml, but the blank checkout.xml file will disable this block regardless.

I know that removing corresponding lines for whatever blocks in catalog.xml removes/doesn't load what I want on the web page, but I'd like to find out why my attempt to "override" callouts isn't working. TIA!

Note: I already have caching disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short version: All those XML files are merged into one giant XML file. Then, during each request, the XML inside certain top level tags (<default>, <catalog_category_index>, etc.; there tags are called handles) are selected, and merged into a smaller XML file.  The nodes left in the smaller XML file are a set of instructions to create certain blocks.  Each (well, most) block has a phtml template file.  When you add stuff to `local.xml`, you're saying "in addition to the normal stuff, do this extra stuff".  When you **replace** an entire file like `catalog.xml`, you're saying "us my file instead", ignore the stuff you normally do.

If you're interested in the long version read [No Frills Magento Layout](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout), my DRM free PDF on the Magento layout system.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to 'overriding' callouts would be this:

/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout" />
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

NB: Alan's answer covers everything else in your question though.